# Close custom multipicklist dropdown on click of another multipicklist

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, locker-service

I have to build an app page with several filters that can be choosen from multiple picklists. There isn't a stantard Lightning Web Components that let me choose multiple options from a picklist component, so I decided to use this custom component:

[MultiPickList custom component](https://github.com/sudikrt/lwc/tree/master/multiPickListDemo)

[Live demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/ijxZKFc5uGVblesakinS)

The component works great but there is a problem: if I open a dropdown to choose some options and then I open another one, the previous one doesn't close. This is the behaviour that I get:

[image]

I put all the multiPickLists inside a `c-filters` parent component but the problem is that because of Lightning Locker I can't access child components DOM elements from the parent. If I try to console.log(this.template.querySelectorAll(".ms-picklist-dropdown")) (the element with the class `ms-picklist-dropdown` is the one that controls if the dropdown is opened or closed with the class `slds-is-open`) from the `c-filters` parent component I don't get any element, so I can't remove the class.

Have you got any idea to help me solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen the standard LWC dual list box? - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-dual-listbox/example

Comment: Yes but I need a dropdown for options...

Comment: That code is terrible. It's not a good example of how to write an LWC. That said, you're also barking up the wrong tree--the component itself should be smart enough to close itself when no longer needed. That's the point of a component. I'm trying to fix this, but it might take a moment (that code is terrible).

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for your support, I really appreciate it. Let me know if you fix this issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code basically suffers from trying to update components outside of itself, resulting in the previous boxes staying open. This was solved by adding/changing the following code:

```
  @track _mOptions = [];
  _isOpen = false;
  _firstOpen = false;
  _docHandler;

  connectedCallback() {
    this._docHandler = () => {
      if(this._isOpen && !this._firstOpen) {
        this.closeAllDropDown();
      }
      this._firstOpen = false;
    };
    document.addEventListener('click', this._docHandler);
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    document.removeEventListener(this._docHandler);
  }
  closeAllDropDown() {
    this._isOpen = false;
  }
  stopPropagation(event) {
    if(!this._firstOpen) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
  onDropDownClick(event) {
    this._firstOpen = this._isOpen = true;
  }
```

And then adding a top-level handler:

```
<div class="slds-form-element" onclick={stopPropagation}>
```

After this, and some more cleanup, the result is a relatively functional dropdown. In the interest of brevity, I'm including a [link to the forked copy of the live demo you provided](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/fOfbFIPHIVWU2v6c8ocf/src/multiPickList.js).

You'll notice a number of quality-of-life improvements in the code, including eliminating all need for `self`, proper use of arrow functions, etc.

As a side note, I will also mention that this code doe not currently support keyboard navigation. This is a major problem, but I won't be addressing it here, as that is an entirely separate problem.

I hope you find this update useful as a starting point.

As a final side note, this code is "interesting", but you should probably start from the [SLDS Combobox](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/) design instead. I realize it means pretty much starting over, but using standard designs helps consolidate the look and feel with Salesforce standard functionality (it's just a shame that lightning-combobox doesn't behave as well as the documented version).

Edit: Also, I noticed some nuance was lost with some of the other functions. You'll want to directly manipulate the data instead of trying to use CSS manipulation as much as possible; this is reflected in the new `visible` property of the options array. You'll need to fix these problems as well.

Comment: Thank you for the fix and for all the advices, you helped me a lot ! :)